# Create interface with generic types

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to create public interface for my class operating on generics.

I've created interface

```
public protocol StorageProtocol {
    associatedtype StorageObject: Codable
    func store(storeObject: StorageObject)
    func get() -> StorageObject?
}
```

and implementation

```
public class Storage<T: Codable>: StorageProtocol {

    public func store(storeObject: T) {}
    public func get() -> T?
```

Now, when I try to create instance it forces me **any** keyword

```
let myStorage: any StorageProtocol = Storage<Credentials>()
```

and I can't call `storage.store(storeObject: Credentials())` as I'm getting error:
*Associated type 'StorageObject' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base*.
What I'm missing here?

Comment: Why not `let myStorage = Storage<Credentials>()`?

Comment: This is simplified but I will use it in dependency injection. I need to operate on protocol to easy replace it in tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not know what type to require in the parameter `storeObject` when you constrain `myStorage` to be `any StoreageProtocol`, as the generic `StorageObject` could be any `Codable` object. A workaround could be to explicitly add a parameter for the type of the generic.

```
public protocol StorageProtocol<StorageObject> { // add a generic parameter
    associatedtype StorageObject: Codable
    func store(storeObject: StorageObject)
    func get() -> StorageObject?
}
```

and then when you define the variable

```
let myStorage: any StorageProtocol<Credentials> = Storage<Credentials>()
```

Then the compiler will know you want to store `Credentials` for this variable and allow you to call `store` as you specialized the protocol to the correct type.